# Retrieving records within a PHP function

Tags: php, mysql, function, records

The following code is taken from a perfect working drop down list, and then when I put it into a function it breaks it! Am I doing something wrong here?

```
<?php

require "connect.php";
//create country lists

function records() {
  $countryOptions = '';
  $query = "SELECT DISTINCT country FROM regions";
  $result = mysql_query($query);
  if (!$result) {
    $countryOptions = "<option>Error Retrieving Records</option>\n";;
    }
  else {
    while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      $countryOptions .= "<option value=\"{$row['country']}\">";
      $countryOptions .= "{$row['country']}";
      $countryOptions .= "</option>\n";
      }
    }
  }

echo records();

?>
```

Comment: You're not returning anything from the function - the `$countryOptions` will be lost

Comment: `;;` really is not necessary in line 11 ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not outputting `$countryOptions` anywhere.

Either add

```
echo $countryOptions;
```

at the end of the function or better yet use

```
return $countryOptions;
```

and call the function like this:

```
echo records();
```

(or implement it to fit your exact needs - it's hard to tell how you use it in your own code)

Comment: Oh my god. I can't believe what a dumb mistake that was :( Thanks for helping. Sometimes you just can't see if you are staring at it for too long.

Comment: Happens ;)  On the other hand - if problems arise after moving code into a function, one should usually look for an issue with variable scope - both on the function input or output.

Comment: NO no, it works perfectly now. I even added some variables already. I just forgot to return it, that was the entire problem :)